# С++ bass dll кириллица

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

Делаю свой плеер на C++ OpenGL Bass dll

в процессе уперся в проблему, русские символы в пути, если открываю через перетягивание файла песню где нет русских символов все играет работает. Картинка 1 вывод строки в консоль окно и текстовый файл с одной переменной.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если есть русские символы музыку не загружает, в консоли крякозябры как и в окне, но при выводе в файл путь адекватный.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать чтобы музыка играла и с русских папок.

пс. при использовании setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"); строка в консоли не изменяться те же кракозябры но другие слова выводит.

**В результате я выяснил что что нужно utf-8 перевести в ansi Должно помочь, но как это сделать?**
[Функция что решила проблему](https://gist.github.com/pezy/8571764)
1

```
// Convert an UTF8 string to a wide Unicode String
std::wstring utf8_decode(const std::string &str)
{
    int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), NULL, 0);
    std::wstring wstrTo(size_needed, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), &wstrTo[0], size_needed);
    return wstrTo;
}
```

Comment: Сдесь все просто: кириллица не может быть закодирована значениями от 0 до 255, поэтому она кодируется двухбайтовыми значениями. К слову: wchar (используется wstring) не имеет фиксированного размера, он может иметь разный размер в зависимости от операционки - 2 или 4 байта.